# Repainting a rectangle at different x, y position canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas layered over a div and I am trying to paint a rectangle at position 0, 0 on load and move it to another position x, y when needed. The x, y positions I need are returning perfectly and I am using the `clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` method to clear the canvas when I need to move and use the `fillRect(x, y, width, height)` again to redraw at those specific positions. However although the x, y positions are good and fillRect(..) is being called (I debugged in chrome) the rectangle is only being removed and painted when I repaint it at position 0, 0. Otherwise it just removes. At first I thought that it is being painted but maybe the layering of the div and canvas is being lost but I positioned it somewhere else and no this was not the problem.

This is the code I have maybe someone could kindly see something wrong in my code! Thanks

```
function removeCursor(connectionId) {
     var canvas = document.getElementById(connectionId);
     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
}

function paintCursor(x, y, connectionId, color) {
     var canvas = document.getElementById(connectionId);
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     context.fillStyle = color;
     context.fillRect(x, y, 0.75, 5);
}

// the canvas is created on someone connecting to a specific page
if (someoneConnected) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id = connectionId;
    canvas.className = 'canvases';
    canvas.style.zIndex = zindex;
    zindex++;

    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("editor-section");
    parentDiv.appendChild(canvas);

    paintCursor(0, 0, connectionId, color);

} else { // someone disconnected

    var canvas = document.getElementById(connectionId);
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
}
```

I call the methods `removeCursor(connectionId)` and `paintCursor(x, y, connectionId, color)` on a user event such as keypress and click. X, Y are the coordinates of the current selection.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: by: "X, Y are the coordinates of the current selection", are you referring to the cursor coords? How are X and Y being determined and in relation to what element?

Comment: actually that is the problem @Nikki! The x and y coordinates are not returning correctly because they are being calculated in terms of the viewport instead of the content editable div. Please see this question maybe you can answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524842/get-x-y-position-of-selection-relative-to-a-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you re-factor to

```
function rePaintCursor(x, y, connectionId, color) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(connectionId);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(x, y, 0.75, 5);
}
```

my guess is that, if x and y are correct, the execution order might be in your way.