# Get x, y position of selection relative to a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div and I need to get the x and y position in pixels of the current selection (i.e. of the caret). What I have now is a method which gets the selection relative to the window i.e. `window.getSelection()`. What I found are methods which return the position in offsets relative to the div node.

Do you have any ideas about this or maybe a plugin? I found plugins that return cursor positions relative to a text area but unfortunately not for a content editable div.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
function getSelectionCoords() {
    var sel = document.selection, range;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();

            range.collapse(true);
            x = range.boundingLeft;
            y = range.boundingTop;
        }
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();

        if (range.getClientRects()) {
            range.collapse(true);
            var rect = range.getClientRects()[0];

            x = rect.left;
            y = rect.top;
        }
      }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
 }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with that code?

Comment: it gets the x and y position relative to the viewport while I want the x and y position of the selection relative to my div so that I can paint a rectangle on a canvas layered on the div at that exact same position.

Comment: That's just a question of calling `getBoundingClientRect()` on your div and subtracting its `left` and `top` from `x` and `y`.

Comment: hmmm.. @TimDown does this work on resizing of the div when the window is resized ?

Comment: Even I have the same doubt :(. Right now I am using a empty span element to calculate the offset position of the caret in contenteditable div. Which is invoking many issues when I am trying to add some HTML tag letters like `<`, `>` or `"`. I asked the same question on [SO though](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16541986/1577396).