# strange behavior of html tags inside contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

In my project, I am trying to add HTML tag letter (`<` and `>`) dynamically to a contenteditable div. Whenever user is pressing alphanumeric character, I am appending an empty `span` element which is used for calculating the position of the caret in contenteditable div.

The problem is that when I type some words like following:

```
when <
```

and press a alphanumeric character like `b` (which calls a function to append a span element), The contenteditable div is showing just `when` instead of `when <b`.

When I inspected the element I found the contenteditable div has the following content:

```
when <b<span class="spanPos"></b<span>
                              ^  strange that span is holding '</b' instead of being empty
```

Here is a example **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPt6B/3/)**.

I am not sure how this is happening. Please tell me what should I do to evade this issue.

PS: Here I am trying to add `<` and `>`, not HTML elements like `<b></b>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually that I was appending a `span` element to the text whenever the user types something in to the contenteditable div to grab the position of the caret. Something like this

```
Hello I am he|re
             ^ Caret position
```

Then I was adding a `span` element in between of that text using `.html()` something like this

```
Hello I am he<span></span>re
```

Now whenever I add any letter which represents Html like `<` or `>`, then it was merging some of the text inside the span (as I shown above in my post).

So, I solved it by removing it just after when I get the position through `span` element. I followed the below steps to solve this issue for each letter pressed by the user.

```
//Store the .text() in a variable.
//Replace Html letters inside the contenteditable div with alphabets which has same width. (for exact positioning).
//add span to the modified text through .html()
//get the offset position of the span 
//Do something with that offset position
//Remove span
//Replace the .text() inside the contenteditable div with the text which was stored in a variable.
```

I did these many things to solve this issue because I was using `.text()` everywhere else in my project code. If I change it to `.html()` then I must have rewritten the complete code and might also can't complete the project.

Clearly, I couldn't have done the things which were mentioned in the other answered posts. I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you're trying to add a symbol which can be interpreted as HTML. You need to escape it or use a different way to express it as an ISO entity:

```
$('#btnContent').click(function(){
    $('#content').html("when &lt;b" + "<span class='spanPos'></span>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dekku/jXeVW/1/

Comment: I tried this before. It was not working. (not in fiddle but in my project, maybe the issue is something else). Thanks I will check it. :)

Comment: You're welcome. You may try to reproduce that issue on another fiddle then. Perhaps it will help you to understand and solve the problem.

Comment: Please check this fiddle. This is what actually happening in my project.. http://jsfiddle.net/nPt6B/3/

Comment: Since `text()` returns the `<` unescaped, and `html()` does not escape it back (text would), you're back at start. In this case it would be simpler to use `$().append()` to add the span.

Comment: I should have explained the question clearly. The problem is that the user an type a letter anywhere in the contenteditable div. So, there is no way of using append here. and I can't use `html` instead of `text` because there are many other functions which are happening related to `text`. Anyway thanks for the help guys. :) If you want to give any suggestions then please give it :) I am in desperate need of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have visit your code and found there is a `<b` in JS don't know by are you using that.

<strike>Use the below code:</strike>

```
$('#btnContent').click(function(){
    $('#content').html("when" + "<span class='spanPos'></span>");
});
```

By removing the `<b` tag you will not get this. or You should properly close to it to make the code proper.

EDITED:

After visiting your new code I got the solution you should use the following code:

```
$('#btnContent').click(function(){
    $('#content').html("when &lt;b");
    $('#content').html($('#content').html()  + "<span class='spanPos'></span>");
});
```

If you need the details then tell me.

Comment: I am using `<b` because I need that to. Please read the question again.

Comment: Your statement is correct but the `.text()` in third line is necessary. which is why I am having this issue. Any fix to this?

Comment: @Mr_Green why you want the `.text()` by this tag you cann't get the html part and this is why you are not able to get the `<b` tag.